# XML, XPath and grouping nodes/attributes on the same level by attribute value

Tags: xml, xslt, xmlstarlet

From much bigger XML I can match a part that I'm interested for further processing. This part is as follows:

```
<Attributes ObjectName="PL1" AttributeName="PL1.CO">
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" FieldName="PL1.CO.0"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.0" FieldType="Struct"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0.0" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.0.class_id" FieldValue="8"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0.0" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.0.logical_name" FieldValue="000000000000"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0.0" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.0.attribute_index" FieldValue="2"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0.0" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.0.data_index" FieldValue="0"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.1" FieldType="Struct"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0.1" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.1.class_id" FieldValue="1"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0.1" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.1.logical_name" FieldValue="CAFEBABE0666"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0.1" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.1.attribute_index" FieldValue="2"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0.1" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.1.data_index" FieldValue="0"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.2" FieldType="Struct"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0.2" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.2.class_id" FieldValue="3"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0.2" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.2.logical_name" FieldValue="FFFFFFFFFFFF"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0.2" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.2.attribute_index" FieldValue="2"/>
    <Fields AttributeName="PL1.CO" ParentFieldName="PL1.CO.0.2" FieldName="PL1.CO.0.2.data_index" FieldValue="0"/>
</Attributes>
```

Of course, number of `<Fields>` nodes within `<Attributes>` node can differ from this example.

Now is a problem: I want to convert this into CSV, but every line should be combined from values of attribute `@FieldValue`:
`class_id;logical_name;attribute_index;data_index`
grouped by common `@ParentFieldName`. In this example output should be:

```
8;000000000000;2;0
1;CAFEBABE0666;2;0
3;FFFFFFFFFFFF;2;0
```

Once again, value of every attribute can be everything, the only thing constant are attribute names.
Is there any method to get this job done? I've been using xmlstarlet, but with no success. Maybe XSLT tranformation? Something other? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: IMHO, XSLT is a way to go for such tasks.

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2/3 you can easily do that with grouping:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="Attributes">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Fields[@FieldValue]" group-by="@ParentFieldName">
          <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/@FieldValue" separator=";"/>
          <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT 3 is supported by Saxon 10 for Java and .NET, by Saxon-C for C/C++ and Python/PHP and by Saxon-JS 2 for JavaScript and Node.js as well as by the various tools from Altova like XMLSpy or Raptor.

As Xidel was mentioned in the other answer, as it also supports XQuery 3.1, there I would use

```
for tumbling window $row in Attributes/Fields
start $s when $s/@FieldType = 'Struct'
return tail($row)!@FieldValue => string-join(';')
```

Comment: Good one! Forgot about windows, tumbling and otherwise :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to replace xmlstarlet with xidel (which supports xpath>1.0). If available, try on your actual xml (indented for readability):

```
xidel  file.xml -e "//Fields[@FieldType='Struct']/concat(    
following-sibling::Fields[contains(@FieldName,'class_id')][1]/@FieldValue,
',',
following-sibling::Fields[contains(@FieldName,'logical_name')][1]/@FieldValue,
',',
following-sibling::Fields[contains(@FieldName,'attribute_index')][1]/@FieldValue,
',',
following-sibling::Fields[contains(@FieldName,'data_index')][1]/@FieldValue 
)"
```

and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet) 1.6.1

```shell
xmlstarlet sel -T -t \
--var sepChar="';'" \
-m 'set:distinct(/*/Fields[@FieldValue]/@ParentFieldName)' \
  --sort 'A:T:-' '.' \
  -m '/*/Fields[@ParentFieldName = current()]' \
    -v 'substring($sepChar, 1, position() != 1)' \
    -v '@FieldValue' \
  -b -n  file.xml
```

to output

```
8;000000000000;2;0
1;CAFEBABE0666;2;0
3;FFFFFFFFFFFF;2;0
```

Grouping by attribute `ParentFieldName` is handled using `-m` option
(`xsl:for-each`) in combination with the [exslt](/questions/tagged/exslt) function
[`set:distinct`](http://exslt.org/set/functions/distinct/index.html),
sorting by parent name as `T`ext in `A`scending order, and
selecting field values from existing `FieldValue` attributes.
(`xmlstarlet` doesn't support `xsl:key`.)

Separation of values takes more work in XSLT 1.0 than in later
versions: in this case a `substring` function call returns an empty
string for the first value where `position() != 1` is false (converted
to number 0), and a separator char for the following where it is true (1).

To list the generated XSLT 1.0 / EXSLT code add `-C` before the `-t` option.